# logOut from Facebook in Android Phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have successfully setup the Facebook Plugin by Jos located (https://github.com/jos3000/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Facebook) - but I can't seem to figure out a way to log the user out. Sure I could tell them to delete the App access on the website then try to login again and click on "Not you?" but I would really rather have a JS Function that does it for me.

Can anyone help provide some guidance on how to do this? I've looked through the files and it looks like there is a way to do it in the facebook.java but I just need to hack something together to connect it to webview. I'm not capable of doing so :) can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi **Henry** i have problem with login in facebook. I dont think you have any problem in login so can u post your code which u are using for login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is to disable the **single sign on** feature in the Facebook plugin

*in FaceBook.java file*

replace **DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE** in the **Authorize** method [2 overloads] by **FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH**

Comment: Thanks Mohamed! This code works to force non-SSO login - which is a good option. BUt I still can't seem to get the below code to work. I get the success callback to work - but It doens't actually do anything. I may know why I think that - what my app does is capture the token and make calls with that. Since your method doesn't revoke access to the app - clearing any cached data doesn't provoke a re-login. I think I'm just goign to leave it as is and instruct users to remove my app on the desktop. Unless you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

in FacebookAuth.Java file 
append this to execute method [in the switch case section]

```
else if (action.equals("performLogout")){
this.performLogout(first);}
```

//Add this method to FacebookAuth.java class

```
 public void performLogout(final String appid) {
    Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "LOGOUT");
    final FacebookAuth fba = this;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            fba.mFb = new Facebook(appid);
            fba.mFb.setPlugin(fba);
            try {
                fba.mFb.logout((Activity) fba.ctx);
                fba.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, ""), fba.callback);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        };
    };
    this.ctx.runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

//in facebook.js file add the following section

```
Facebook.prototype.Logout = function(app_id,callback){
PhoneGap.exec(callback,null, "FacebookAuth", "performLogout", [app_id]); };
```

// in your page add the following code

```
function LogoutClick() //on logout click
{   
    appId = "123" ; //your app Id
    window.plugins.facebook.Logout(appId,CompleteLogout);
}   

function CompleteLogout() //call back function
{
    //do some logic for callback
}
```

//Enjoy..!!

Comment: Thank you Mohamed! It looks like this method is making a call to https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=auth.expireSession&format=json
is that a safe way to log out? Facebook is deprecating that method currently. Also, I'm not sure if it's working... I believe this should expire my Access Token and make me need to re-request one? For what ever reason it isn't working and I don't know enough Java to troubleshoot. Is there a way to get the callback to display Facebook's response? That may help me troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Henry , This is not exactly how it works, it simply clear your application facebook cookies so the next time you need to login , facebook will show you the email/password form.

Comment: and it doesn't call Facebook API so , you have logged out from the application itself , not from the Facebook

Comment: If you can to tell me what it does with you , i mean after you tried to logout and then login again because there is an option in this plugin to use the email/password stored at the facebook standalone application and you can disable it , i will post the fix to disable this option and use only the data stored within your application.

Comment: I post it below how to disable the single sign on feature in this plugin , try it and let me know please